# Strange behaviour of bash when finding executable

Tags: macos, bash, python-3.x, osx-mavericks

I'm developing a Python application that internally has to invoke the `ninja` command, but it couldn't find the executable with the `subprocess` module. When I pass `shell=True`, it *does find* the executable, but doesn't pass arguments to the process. Using  `os.system()` worked.

```
subprocess.call(['ninja'] + args)              # Can't find ninja
subprocess.call(['ninja'] + args, shell=True)  # Finds & runs ninja, but the additional arguments int "args" are not passed
os.system(' '.join(shlex.quote(x) for x in ['ninja'] + args))  # Works fine
```

When I check where `ninja` is in the `bash`, things start to seem strange to me.

```
$ which ninja
$ type ninja
ninja is hashed (/Users/niklas/Bin/ninja)
$ echo $PATH
~/Bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/texbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/:/Users/niklas/Documents/apache-maven-3.3.3/bin:/Users/niklas/Documents/grib2json-0.8.0-SNAPSHOT/bin
```

1. `which` can't find `ninja`
2. `type ninja` yields it is located at `/Users/niklas/Bin/ninja`
3. The path `/Users/niklas/Bin` is not in `$PATH`

What's gone wrong with my setup here? Why can the bash actually find `ninja`, but Python only in `shell=True` mode, and then why are the additional arguments not passed?

Comment: You probably have hash -p ... ninja in your .bashrc or in some similar bans profile file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `~` is a bashism, whereas python is calling os.execvp() to do the subprocess.call(), and this is obviously using execvp(), the system call, which **does not do tilde expansion**.

Your PATH should read  `/Users/niklas/Bin:...`. The tilde expansion is usually done by the shell when you set `PATH=~/Bin:$PATH`.

So bash can find it because it re-does tilde expansion each time, but an execvp() will never find it.

And as @larsks said, `shell=True` needs a single string.

Answer (score 1):

If you are setting `shell=True`, then your command must be a string rather than a list.  Consider:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call(['echo', 'hello'], shell=True)

0
>>> subprocess.call('echo hello', shell=True)
hello
0
```

If you pass a list with `shell=True`, only the first item of the list is considered:

```
>>> subprocess.call(['echo hello', 'hello'], shell=True)
hello
0
>>>
```

> The path /Users/niklas/Bin is not in $PATH

Yes it is.  It's the first item there:

```
$ echo $PATH
~/Bin:/usr/local/bin:...
```

...assuming that you are `niklas`.